# Are telescoping sums related to the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I just noticed that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - a_{i-1})=a_n-a_0$$
and
$$\int_a^b f'(x)\mathrm{d}x=f(b)-f(a)$$
look really similar.
We can consider $a_i-a_{i-1}$ a discrete analog to the derivative of continuous functions.

Is there anything deep between those equations?

Comment: Do you know the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus? Because in it, you use precisely the fist equation you noticed.

Comment: Read the master, http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Trig/, section 4 where Riemann uses exactly this kind of reasoning to introduce the Riemann sums.

Comment: @5xum That is cool! Thank you!

Comment: @LutzL Is there a translation of this in english?

Comment: Excellent observation. Check out the calculus of finite differences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: Yes, I mention that frequently in my posts here on telescopy, e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1803901/242). You can learn more in any textbook on (Boole's) difference calculus

Comment: Incredible post @BillDubuque!

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro: Not that I know of.

Comment: @Lutzl: Great ref! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$

So we have

$$\int_a^bf'(x)dx=\lim_{h\to0}\int_a^b\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}hdx$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left(\int_a^bf(x+h)-f(x)dx\right)$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left(\int_a^bf(x+h)dx-\int_a^bf(x)dx\right)$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left(\int_{a+h}^{b+h}f(x)dx-\int_a^bf(x)dx\right)$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left(\int_b^{b+h}f(x)dx-\int_a^{a+h}f(x)dx\right)\tag1$$

$$=f(b)-f(a)\tag2$$

You may graph or look at Riemann sums to see the last step above $(2)$.

Consider your telescoping sum for $(1)$.

Comment: Why can you "comute" the limit with the integral in your second equation? And I didn't understood why (1) is true or why it is related to a telescopic sum.

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro The limit is with respect to $h$, which is a constant with respect to $x$, and any constant can be comuted or factored out through an integral.  $(1)$ is related to telescoping sums if you graph it (the gray area is where the integrals cancel, in a "telescoping" like manner): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a4qbpc8ckb

Comment: The graph was really helpful! Thanks