# Using Induction to Prove Divisibiility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

If I were to prove $2\mid n^2+n$ for all integers $n$, would the following proof by induction be valid?

---

**Base**: $2\mid 1^2+1 = 2$, so this is obviously true.

**Hypothesis**: $2 \mid (k^2+k) \to 2 \mid ((k+1)^2+(k+1))$

**Induction**:
\begin{align} &2 \mid k^2 + k \to 2 \mid (k+1)^2 + (k+1)\\
&2 \mid k^2+k\\
&2 \mid 2 \quad \therefore 2 \mid 2(k+1) \quad \because 2 \mid a \to 2 \mid ac \quad \text{for all integers} \ c \ \text{(in this case} \ a=2, c=k+1)\\ 
&(2 \mid 2k+2) \wedge (2 \mid k^2+k)\\
&2 \mid k^2+k+2k+2 \quad \because (2 \mid a) \wedge (2 \mid b) \to (2 \mid a+b)\\
&2 \mid k^2+3k+2\\
&2 \mid k^2 +2k+1+(k+1)\\
&2 \mid (k+1)^2+(k+1)\\
\end{align}
Therefore, by the principle of mathematical induction we conclude that $2 \mid n^2+n$.

---

I think it all makes sense, but I'm not sure if it properly qualifies as induction. Please let me know if I'm missing any steps/made any incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Looks about okay to me.

Comment: I would say that it's missing all the words: it's all symbols! But I guess some people think that makes it look more "mathematical" or something.

Comment: It seems like you may have the correct idea but it is impossible to be sure since you omit the logical connectives necessary to uniquely parse your argument. Here's is a clearer way to do the inductive step. Let $\,f_k = k^2+k.\,$ Then $2\mid f_{k+1} = f_k + 2(k\!+\!1)$ by $\,2\mid 2(k\!+\!1)$ and $\,2\mid f_k\,$ (by induction hypothesis). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3637323/242) for how to view this more *intuitively* via "telescopic" cancellation.

Answer (score -1):

Your induction solution is correct.

---

By the way, here's my solution without induction -- it makes it a whole lot simpler, unless I'm being stupid.

---

Exactly one out of two consecutive integers is even, so $n(n+1)$ is even. But $n(n+1)=n^2+n$, so this proves that our desired expression is even as well. $\square$

---

I hope this helped.

Comment: Or alternatively, $n$ and $n^2$ give the same remainder when divided by 2. Therefore, adding $n^2$ and $n$ then taking remainder when divided by 2 is the same as dividing $2n$ by $2$ and finding remainder, which is $0$.

Comment: Also I am guessing that OP needs it to be done through induction, but is aware of alternative proofs.